# Restore transaction in in-app purchase iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I had configured a non-consumable product in iTunes connect and i am able to purchase and restore that product (obviously in sandbox). Initially this is all working as expected, but now when i try to restore the product, i got a call back on the failure method

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error`

with this error description

**Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes Store}**

I can purchase the product using the same user account but cannot restore the product after reinstalling the app. When i try to purchase the same product again i got the usual message from the Apple that i had bought this product earlier(as expected). So i think issue is related with restoring the in-app purchase module.

This [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2413/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40016228-CH1-ERROR_MESSAGES-CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_ITUNES_STORE) didn't help me either.

I have tried with different sandbox user accounts and all have the same issue.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you on simulator or real device?

Comment: Real device iPhone 6S iOS version 9.2.1

Comment: Something like that happened to me, my solution was logout from the Settings-> iTunes Store & App Store, and then click on restore purchases on my app and login from there.

Comment: i tried that as well, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me once before, and apparently happened to other people [in the past](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17500).

If you are sure that your code is correct, give it some time and try again later. It's probably not what you wanted to hear, but it happens with the In-App Purchase mechanism.

**Edit:** Other people are starting to report about an issue with restoring purchases in the sandbox environment, see [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43419).

Comment: This is exactly my problem. Yesterday the restore purchase functionality is working  for me. Today i have seen this error message. Actually i have been stuck with problem for 6 hours. Hope this is Apple's issue. Thanks buddy

Comment: It's frustrating, but it happens sometimes with the App Store. Good luck!

Comment: @Unni See my edit, it happens to other people, too. Did it resolve itself?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to confirm that I am seeing the same behaviour as of 24th March 2016 (sandbox environment).  My code was verified as working; no code was changed and I am seeing the same behaviour you observe. Ergo this is a problem on Apple's side and unfortunately we just have to wait until they resolve it. It has been reported it on the Apple developer forums.

See e.g. [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43419)

Comment: Thanks, but it has not yet started working for me.  I still receive "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" from restoreTransactionsFailedWithError. This is on the UK Sandbox store - which territory are you in @Unni?